Roger Corman, legendary (B movie) filmmaker, has died
Roger Corman, low-budget filmmaker who launched many careers, dies at 98

Roger Corman, a low-budget but resourceful Hollywood filmmaker who churned out dozens of laughably ridiculous and ridiculously profitable movies about crab monsters, a human-eating plant and buxom women in prison, and who helped launch the careers of Jack Nicholson, Francis Ford Coppola and other promising actors and directors, died May 9 at his home in Santa Monica, Calif. He was 98.

....

There have been mavericks working outside the major studio system since the earliest days of film, but few have been so stingy and so financially successful for so long as Mr. Corman. He entered the business in the 1950s, just as a U.S. Supreme Court antitrust ruling loosened the tight grip that a few big studio bosses had long exerted over the production and distribution of movies.
Mr. Corman became one of the most commercially successful filmmakers of all time, but his films rarely warranted consideration by mainstream critics. He worked in a remarkable array of genres — horror, gangster, western, science fiction, the drug movie — and he was applauded by a core of devoted followers and even some reviewers for flashes of craftsmanship and a playful sense of the absurd.


No idea who he was, but I'm all for non-mainstream work of "art"

He knew how to take a budget and spend it in the most efficient way to turn a decent profit. Seemed utterly pragmatic, his films didn't need to be outstanding, they just needed to be "good enough" to make financial sense. I'd be interested to see some numbers - he might have been making low budget pictures with low box offices compared to big pictures, but if you were to take his average % profit compared to budget, he'd be up there with the best.

IMDB has a scene with him from Death Race 2050. Quintessential Corman

I want to say this: I grew up watching Corman's films. I had hoped, although this was not very realistic, to meet him one day, but time was not on my side in this.
Corman worked with small budgets but his films imho were far better than most of the low-budget scifi of the 1950s and 1960s. His The Day the World Ended had some amazing dialog and decent acting. I will miss him. He was one of the last connections with movies of the increasingly distant past.
